# How can i stdout.read() parse in

Tags: python, parsing, ssh, paramiko

Hello guys i get ipconfig values from stdout.read() but its look like these

```
   **b'PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms\n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.01 ms\n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms\n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms\n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms\n\n--- localhost ping statistics ---\n5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4000ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.052/0.256/1.014/0.379 ms\n'**
```

**i need to parse them like normal ipconfig how can i do it?**

```
import paramiko


hostname = '192.168.xx.xxx'
port = 22
username = 'root'
password = 'xxxxxxx'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.load_system_host_keys()
    s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr =s.exec_command('ping localhost -c 5')
    print(stdout.read())
    s.close()
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean like a `normal ipconfig`

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by **normal** ipconfig and fix your question's title.

Comment: İ want get  these values line by line i wanna parse them in lines

Comment: `stdout.read().decode().split()`

Comment: Nope not like this i want all of them like line1:n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.106   Line2:n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.01 ms Line3:n64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

Comment: Ok i found that thanks

Comment: for line in stdout.read().splitlines():   print(line)

Comment: If you are just printing, you van leave out the last `.split()` as that will create a list of lines. So, do `stdout.read().decode()`. However, it assumes that you are able to read all the input from `stdin` in one go.

Comment: Of course I mean `splitlines()` rather than `split()` as you wrote.